# how can i find the most frequent character for each position in a file full of strings and return the highest frequent characters for each position

Tags: python, string, character

I can't seem to understand the part where you have to do it for each position of the string and return the highest frequent character for example if i have like multiple strings in the file:'house', 'garden', 'kitchen','balloon','home','park','affair','kite','hello','portrait','angel','surfing' and the return value should be:'hareennt'
I can't use import libraries

I have tried

```
max(set(item),key=item.count)
```

but it works for like each element not each character

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution:**

```py
import itertools
from statistics import mode

words = ['house', 'garden', 'kitchen', 'balloon', 'home', 'park', 'affair', 'kite', 'hello', 'portrait', 'angel', 'surfing']

list(map(lambda x: mode(sorted(filter(lambda v: v != None, x))), (itertools.zip_longest(*words))))
```

In a slightly more legible form:

```py
import itertools
from statistics import mode

# Tranpose the list to group characters based on their position in words
char_list = itertools.zip_longest(*words)

# Remove None values and sort alphabetically
char_list_filter = map(lambda x: filter(lambda v: v != None, x), char_list)
char_list_sorted = map(sorted, char_list_filter)

# Use the mode function from statistics module
char_list_mode = map(mode, char_list_sorted)

# Print results
print( ''.join(char_list_mode))
```